# convert minute into hours sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to convert minutes into hours in sql server.

I used following logic to do it.

```
 CAST(REPLACE(LEFT(CONVERT(varchar(10), DATEADD(MINUTE, 19.80 *100, ''), 114),5),':','.')    AS Decimal(5,2)) AS tpschedhours
```

My expected Output is `33` hours (1980 minutes in hours)

But I got output as 9 hours.   I have found that, the issue occurs because   `DATEADD(MINUTE,1980, '')` returns ouptut as `1900-01-02 09:00:00.000`   (One day + 9 hours). But I need the Output as Hours value i.e 33 hours

Thanks for the help

Comment: `SELECT 1980  / 60 + (1980  % 60) / 100.0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Got the solution from the answers.

```
SELECT CAST((CAST(((2.72) *100)AS INT) / 60 )+ (CAST((2.72 *100)AS INT) % 60) / 100.0 AS DECIMAL(5,2)).
```

thanks tinka and  Stanislovas Kalašnikovas

Comment: be sure to upvote them if they were helpful, and accept one of them if it was the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can try in following:

```
DECLARE @time INT = 1980

SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(MINUTE, @time / 60 + (@time % 60), ''),114),5)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(5), 
       DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute, @StartDate, @EndDate), 0), 114)
```